# Determine Distance between two specific elements in an array?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an NSMutableArray that is loaded into a table view. The data in this array is basically storing the dates in the form (i.e Sun, Mar 6, 2011, etc). The user adds these days by pressing an "add" button at the top of the nav bar (and today's date is added). Now they will not necessarily add all the days of the week for a specific week (i.e. they may miss adding a day). Therefore I can't assume that there are always 7 days (7 entries in the array) until I hit a specific day of the week again (i.e. from Sun, Mar 6, 2011 to Sun, Mar 13, 2011). Each entry in the array is storing an NSMutableDictionary with a bunch of data. Finally I want to calculate a specific value that needs to take into account the sum of the data for each consecutive week in the NSArray (between a specific day chosen by the user, i.e. sun).

Hopefully I've explained my situation in an understandable way. I've hit a major road block here, can someone help me out.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not really sure i got what you mean, but if you are just asking how to compare 2 different dates this could help:

```
NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [aNSDate timeIntervalSinceDate: oldNSDate];
NSLog(@"+%.02f sec"), timeDifference]];
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the distance between two entries in your array, you can use `[array indexOfObject:o]` to get the index for each and subtract.

But for the task you describe (summing data for each week in the array), it sounds like it would work better for you to iterate through the array and accumulate your results in a mutable dictionary keyed by each week's starting date.